# can't import .p12 file into MS Certificate Store

Tags: java, rsa, pkcs#12, key-pair

I have the following test code to create test PKCS#12 keystore:

```
X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];    
long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
Date firstDate = new Date(currentTime - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
long validity = (long) 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 365;
Date lastDate = new Date(currentTime + validity * 1000);
String myName = "CN=TestKeys, L=Test, C=US";

X509V3CertificateGenerator cg = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

cg.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(firstDate.getTime()));
cg.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1withRSA");
cg.setSubjectDN(new X500Principal(myName));

if ( publicKey==null ) {
    throw new Exception("Public key is null");
}
cg.setPublicKey(publicKey);
cg.setNotBefore(firstDate);
cg.setNotAfter(lastDate);
cg.setIssuerDN(new X500Principal(myName));

chain[0] = cg.generate(keyPair.getPrivate());

char[] pwd = "0000000000000000".toCharArray();

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(null, pwd);
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pwd);
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(privateKey, chain);
ks.setEntry("keypair", pkEntry, protParam);

String keyStoreFile = "rsakey.p12";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile);
ks.store(fos, pwd);
fos.close();
```

Then I want to import created `rsakey.p12` into MS Certificate Store but I get the following error:

> An internal error occurred. This can be either the user profile is not
>   accessible or the private key that you are importing might require a
>   cryptographic service provider that is not installed on your system.

This happens when the `privateKey` is instance of `RSAPrivateKey`. When `privateKey` is instance of `RSAPrivateCRTKey` then import works.

You can see samples of two files through the following link:
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=321f74d3665268eb&id=321F74D3665268EB%2120994

- `rsakey.p12` is created with above mentioned code and privateKey as
  `RSAPrivateCRTKey` - can be imported to MS
- `rsakey-not.p12` is created with above mentioned code and privateKey as `RSAPrivateKey` - can't be imported to MS

What's the difference? Why import works only with `RSAPrivateCRTKey`?

Comment: I would imagine it depends on what the underlying class is. It may be that MSCAPI only accepts private keys with all the components, eg a CRT key.

Comment: The second key is 2047 bit.