# p12 file import failure in windows certificate store by forge JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, webcrypto-api

I am using [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#pkcs10) library to create a self signed certificate in .p12 format which generates private-public key pair using [WebCryptoAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). But when i am trying to import the .p12 file in windows certificate store, i am getting the following error :

[image]

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436529/cant-import-p12-file-into-ms-certificate-store) says that there might be issue with private key.

Following is my key generation snippet by webcryptoApi

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: 'RSA-PSS',
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
    hash: {name: 'SHA-1'}
  }
```

And my forge code snippet to generate p12 is as follows :

```
var newPkcs12Asn1 = forge.pkcs12.toPkcs12Asn1(
keys.privateKey, [cert], password,
{generateLocalKeyId: true, friendlyName: 'test'},
{algorithm: '3des'});

var newPkcs12Der = forge.asn1.toDer(newPkcs12Asn1).getBytes();
var p12b64 = forge.util.encode64(newPkcs12Der);

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = "example.p12";
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
downloadLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/x-pkcs12;base64,' + p12b64);
downloadLink.style.display = "none";

downloadLink.click();
```

Note :

- I am unable to import the file in Mozilla certificate store also. So
  there might be issue with the p12 file ?
- Windows certificate store validating my private key password properly while importing, only finish stage fails.

Comment: is `keys.privateKey` in forge format (exported from webcrypto)? I guess `{generateLocalKeyId: true, friendlyName: 'test'},
{algorithm: '3des'}` is a typo. It think it should be `{generateLocalKeyId: true, friendlyName: 'test',algorithm: '3des'}`

Comment: Could you try with `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` instead of `RSA-PSS` ? . Just to check if Windows supports it. Try also to open the .p12 with KeystoreExplorer

Comment: Actually `algorithm: '3des'` was the issue. I corrected the syntax error. It is now working for both `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` and `RSA-PSS`. But without `3des` it doesn't work. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in comments, the problem is a syntax error in the pkcs12 encoding params

```
 {generateLocalKeyId: true, friendlyName: 'test',algorithm: '3des'}
```

It is needed  to set `algorithm: '3des'` because forge by default encrypts p12 with aes-128.

As can be read in this [article](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=543) the RFC7292 that standarizes PKCS#12, doesn’t specify a need to support AES,  but there is enough information to use it in an interoperable way. Windows (even windows10)is not able to work with files produced with more secure encryption schemes and ciphers. Then, the most secure algorithm that can be used is triple-des